# Screen needs mode 777 with systemd service

Tags: boot, 16.04, server, services, minecraft

I am trying to set up Minecraft to run in a screen session on start-up. but with the following service file, bellow is my status of my service.

I am new to using the Systemd way of boot services so any help would be appreciated.

```
minecraft.service - Minecraft Server
Loaded: loaded (/home/matt/minecraft.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Fri 2016-12-16 14:17:59 GMT; 6min ago
Process: 15942 ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/screen -X -S Minecraft exit (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 15940 ExecStop=/var/minecraft/mcrcon -H localhost -P 8101 -p drwho stop (code=exited, status=255)
Process: 15990 ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -X -S Minecraft /usr/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar spigot.jar (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 15985 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/screen -dmS Minecraft (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 15990 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 16 14:17:59 TheCyberman systemd[1]: Starting Minecraft Server...
Dec 16 14:17:59 TheCyberman screen[15985]: Directory '/var/run/screen' must have mode 777.
Dec 16 14:17:59 TheCyberman systemd[1]: Started Minecraft Server.
Dec 16 14:17:59 TheCyberman screen[15990]: Directory '/var/run/screen' must have mode 777.
```

This is my Service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
Documentation=

Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
User=minecraft
Group=minecraft
Nice=5
EnvironmentFile=-/var/minecraft/unit.conf
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1
RemainAfterExit=yes

ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full
PrivateDevices=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
PrivateTmp=true
InaccessibleDirectories=/root /sys /srv -/opt /media -/lost+found
ReadWriteDirectories=/var/minecraft/server /usr/bin/screen
WorkingDirectory=/var/minecraft/server
ExecStartPre= /usr/bin/screen -dmS Minecraft 
ExecStart= /usr/bin/screen -X -S Minecraft '/usr/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar spigot.jar'
ExecStop=/var/minecraft/mcrcon -H localhost -P 8101 -p drwho stop
ExecStopPost= /usr/bin/screen -X -S Minecraft 'exit'
ExecReload=/var/minecraft/mcrcon -H localhost -P 8101 -p drwho reload
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The directory needs full permissions to read, write, and execute.

You can do this command `chmod -R 777 /var/run/screen`

Which will recursively change all folders/files permissions to 777, though typically less secure.

You can also run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/run/screen`

This will allow a typical user/or group full access, and will be more secure.

Comment: this does not work
screen[29361]: Directory '/run/screen' must have mode 775.
screen[4168]: Directory /run/screen/S-root must have mode 700.

Answer (score 0):

Change `NoNewPrivileges=true` to `NoNewPrivileges=false`.  This will allow screen to run in setgid mode, like it usually does, so it won't ask for 777 permissions.